# async function returning UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with try/catch (axios)

Tags: node.js, async-await, axios, try-catch

I'm getting an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning for an async function that has a try/catch block. What am I missing?

```
// In local module http.js
async function get(url, callback) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url)
        if (callback) {
            callback(null, response.data)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("GET failed to "+url+" - "+err);
        callback(err)
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function like this. I'm not using await here because I expect the results with a callback:

```
http.get(config.hostController+"/v0/portal/subscribers/"+req.session.subscriberId, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        return res.status(err).send(response)
    }
    return res.send(response)
})
```

I am hitting the catch because I am seeing the "GET failed to" message. (I am expecting a 404 error). But I still get this error:

```
GET failed to http://localhost:7991/v0/portal/subscribers/SUB-b4ae-2ed6 - Error: Request failed with status code 404
(node:23948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/Users/sjohnson/github/netreach/netreach-portal/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/sjohnson/github/netreach/netreach-portal/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/sjohnson/github/netreach/netreach-portal/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  config: [Object],
  request: [ClientRequest],
  response: [Object],
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practise to mix between async functions and callbacks, u should use only the async await method. This is because there are mix of scopes that the error is thrown and this may cause unhandled promises rejection errors

U have 2 options to implement it as shown below using the async/await only:

```
// option 1 that 'get' don't throw the error but always return
async function get(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    return { data: response.data };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`GET failed to ${url} - ${error}`);
    return { error };
  }
}

async function controller(res) {
  const result = await http.get(`${config.hostController}/v0/portal/subscribers/${req.session.subscriberId}`);
  if (result.error) {
    // u can take the status from the error or come up with your own
    return res.status(500).send({ error: result.error });
  }
  return res.send(result.data);
}


// option 2 that 'get' throw the error
async function get(url) {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  return response.data;
}

async function controller(res) {
  try {
    const result = await http.get(`${config.hostController}/v0/portal/subscribers/${req.session.subscriberId}`);
    return res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    // u can take the status from the error or come up with your own
    return res.status(500).send({ error });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the exception was a secondary error. When I returned an error, `callback(err)`, I was returning a string. I then tried to use `err` as an http status code. Returning `err.response.status` instead fixed the problem.